# Microsoft Visual Studio: How to keep the console open without manually reading input?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, unit-testing, console, visual-studio-express

I'm writing some C++ with Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Express, and I'm wondering if there is a way to display command output somewhere in the IDE instead of an external console window, or at least keep that window open.

Reading something from STDIN would work for a console application, but this is a unit test case and I don't want to modify the generated main function. Is there another way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ctrl + F5
for quick test.
The key combination keeps the console open until you close it.

Comment: This. You don't need to write any artificial code to do this.

Comment: Brilliant, works! Just curious: is there no menu option for this?

Comment: It used to be under the Debug drop menu in MSVS 2008 Express but removed in 2010 Express. The full version of MSVS 2010 still has it under Debug: Start Without Debugging, Ctrl + F5

Answer (score 2):

I've found a solution that is not really elegant, but at least it works. I'm using a fixture in my unit testing framework (Boost.Test) which does `system("pause")` in the tear down method:

```
struct Global_fixture {
    Global_fixture() {}

    ~Global_fixture()
    {
        system("pause");
    }
};
BOOST_GLOBAL_FIXTURE(Global_fixture)
```

I hope you guys can find a better way.

Comment: Very useful if Ctrl-F5 doesn't work (e.g. you need /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE for the Ctrl-F5 to work and using NMAKE/SCons I haven't figured out how to do that yet)

Comment: @danio See my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/454681/how-to-keep-the-console-window-open-in-visual-c/23288778#23288778) for how to fix the bug which prevents it working in makefile projects.

Comment: @JBentley thanks, SCons generates the vcxproj so patching it to be to add that tag would be a solution

Answer (score 1):

In c++ you want to use : `OutputDebugString`

Answer (score 0):

I think Debug.Write (and related) should do what you're looking for.  Writes to the VS output window.

Comment: I don't think I can (or want to) fiddle with Boost.Test until it uses that instead of stdout.

Answer (score 0):

If you're running unit tests, you're not debugging, right? So use "Run withut debugging" and the console window will stay open.

Alternatively, open a command prompt of your own and launch the exe by typing its name.

Comment: I'm usually running in "Debug" mode, is that what you mean? Doesn't stay open.

Comment: @futlib, right, I'm suggesting you run it _not_ in Debug mode.

Comment: I got the same behaviour in Release mode.

Comment: Debug/Release is what kind of build you are making. I am not talking about that. Ctrl-F5  or Debug, Run Without Debugging is the command I want you to try.

Answer (score 0):

In VC++ use

```
Console::WriteLine(L"my error text");
```

Printf won't produce any output. Neither will OutputDebugString. The Console will write at the bottom of the test results output, so all you have to do is double-click on the test in the "Test Results" window.

Comment: There is no Console::WriteLine in VC++. You probably mixed with C#