# Win32 console disapears after a second

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I have created a Win32 Console Application in Visual Studio but when I start the program the console apears just for a second and then disapears again. What should I do that the console remains on the screen ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to keep the console window open in visual c++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/454681/how-to-keep-the-console-window-open-in-visual-c)

Comment: Use the search button please. This question has been asked upwards of a million times

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, the program has finished running, so it closes.

Either make the program wait for input (e.g. with `getchar()`), or press Ctrl-F5 to run the program without debugging (but then you won't be able to set breakpoints and stuff).

Comment: @MichaelBurr: I was going to mention that, but for a beginner it might be confusing because the window suddenly goes away into the background. :)

Comment: The problem with a breakpoint is that the IDE will automatically pop up to the front, obscuring the console window. Yes, it will work, but it adds an extra step.

Comment: All true, but I suppose it depends on what you want to do - if you're debugging you either set a breakpoint and go through the extra step of bringing the window back in front of the debugger, or you take the other step of adding a `getchar()` that you really don't want in the program (so don't forget to take it back out). In all honesty, I don't know why F5 doesn't behave the same as Ctrl-F5 as far as this bit of behavior goes.  I know that I would rather it did.

Comment: I use conditional compilation to insert a `getchar()` statement or equivalent. Something like `#ifdef DEBUG`, just to be sure that I don't forget to take it out.

Answer (score 0):

You can set breakpoints anywhere in your code to make it stop.  If you just want to see the output of the program when it's done, try setting a breakpoint on the last line of main().

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because the program has nothing to wait for before exiting.

Try running `std::cin.get();` before `main()` returns to make the console wait for keyboard input.