# visual studio 2012 hello world c++

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Just installed visual studio 2012 ultimate trial (dull and gray!).

But after starting an 'empty' c++ console project and add one source file with this code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() 
{
cout << "Hello World" << endl;

return 0;
}
```

I get the following errors:

> 'Project3.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Users\baobei\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Project3\Debug\Project3.exe'. Symbols loaded.
>   'Project3.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
>   'Project3.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\kernel32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
>   'Project3.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\KernelBase.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
>   'Project3.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcp110d.dll'. Symbols loaded.
>   'Project3.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcr110d.dll'. Symbols loaded.
>   The program '[6932] Project3.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).

What am I doing wrong? Thanks for advice.

Comment: I think it's just closing too fast for you to see, but running fine nonetheless.

Comment: Did u build it before run ???

Answer (score 4):

I do not think that you are doing anything wrong. `The program '[6932] Project3.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).` indicates that your program has been running - try returning something else than 0 from `main()`, you should then see a different exit code.

I think your issue is that the output console closes immediately, so that you do not have a chance to see the output. See [How to keep the console window open in Visual C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/454681/how-to-keep-the-console-window-open-in-visual-c) for some solutions.