# How to add an element to xml file by using elementtree

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I've a xml file, and I'm trying to add additional element to it.
the xml has the next structure :

```
<root>
  <OldNode/>
</root>
```

What I'm looking for is :

```
<root>
  <OldNode/>
  <NewNode/>
</root>
```

but actually I'm getting next xml :

```
<root>
  <OldNode/>
</root>

<root>
  <OldNode/>
  <NewNode/>
</root>
```

My code looks like that :

```
file = open("/tmp/" + executionID +".xml", 'a')
xmlRoot = xml.parse("/tmp/" + executionID +".xml").getroot()

child = xml.Element("NewNode")
xmlRoot.append(child)

xml.ElementTree(root).write(file)

file.close()
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 18):

You opened the file for appending, which adds data to the end. Open the file for writing instead, using the `w` mode. Better still, just use the `.write()` method on the ElementTree object:

```
tree = xml.parse("/tmp/" + executionID +".xml")

xmlRoot = tree.getroot()
child = xml.Element("NewNode")
xmlRoot.append(child)

tree.write("/tmp/" + executionID +".xml")
```

Using the `.write()` method has the added advantage that you can set the encoding, force the XML prolog to be written if you need it, etc.

If you *must* use an open file to prettify the XML, use the `'w'` mode, `'a'` opens a file for appending, leading to the behaviour you observed:

```
with open("/tmp/" + executionID +".xml", 'w') as output:
     output.write(prettify(tree))
```

where `prettify` is something along the lines of:

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree
from xml.dom import minidom

def prettify(elem):
    """Return a pretty-printed XML string for the Element.
    """
    rough_string = ElementTree.tostring(elem, 'utf-8')
    reparsed = minidom.parseString(rough_string)
    return reparsed.toprettyxml(indent="  ")
```

e.g. the minidom prettifying trick.