# insert xml string from a dicttoxml object into a lxml.etree

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have an `etree.Element` that basically just looks like `<Root></Root>`.

I want to insert a bunch of children elements which come from `children = dicttoxml(dict, root=False)`.

The latter gives me a number of elements without a parent, so basically doing `print children` gives me this:

```
<Child1></Child1>
<Child2></Child2>
<Child3></Child3>
<Child4></Child4>
```

I want to insert `children` into my root `etree.Element` so, this:

```
<Root>
   <Child1></Child1>
   <Child2></Child2>
   <Child3></Child3>
   <Child4></Child4>
</Root>
```

Comment: Have you seen http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14440375/how-to-add-an-element-to-xml-file-by-using-elementtree ? It uses the `append` method

Comment: it seems to me `append` only works if the appended element is a single element though

Comment: In that case, if `children` is iterable, you could loop over it: `for c in children: root.append(c)`