# Debugging a solution and the test output is visible for less than a second

Tags: c++, unit-testing, visual-c++, googletest

I'm having a problem with visual studio. I'm trying to run a unit test using the Google test framework and the output keeps flickering on for a sec and disappearing. How do I keep the output the executable shows on the screen so that I can see the results of the test?

It worked previously but I changed some of the settings (can't remember what) and now it just flickers on and off.

Comment: Agree with Igor, but you might need to set it up as outlined in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/454681/how-to-keep-the-console-window-open-in-visual-c), in the second answer.

Answer (score 0):

Run it with Debug > Start Without Debugging (Ctrl+F5) rather than Start Debugging (F5). When you do that, the IDE keeps the console open and waits for a key press after the program exits.

Comment: A Release build would keep the Window open as well.