# Visual Studio can't debug a console application in C#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging, build

Upon writing any console application with C# and trying to run it (even the simplest of code), I get an error noise, the status bar at the bottom turns from blue to orange, the program doesn't run, and something about IntelliTrace pops up at the right.
http://i.imgur.com/MWFH6gH.png

And then after a couple of seconds, it goes back to a blue status bar and stops running.

However, when I run without debugging (Ctrl+F5) it runs fine.
http://i.imgur.com/KjrGNwp.png

I've also ran the program from the directory\bin\Debug\ConsoleApplication.exe and it runs fine.

Anyone know what the problem is?

Comment: What happens when you [disable IntelliTrace?](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264948(v=vs.100).aspx)

Comment: -1 for your title. Learn to use your tools before claiming/suggesting that they "can't do stuff".

Comment: Set a breakpoint. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/454681/how-to-keep-the-console-window-open-in-visual-c

Comment: A question mark usually does not signify a claim.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Also try to provide smaller screenshots. It's not necessary to see that you edit StackOverflow questions on the second screen. If the pictures are small enough, you can also embed them directly into code, so that we needn't open it in another window.

Answer (score 0):

Everything is working as expected. Your program does run, it's just that all output of the console application goes to Visual Studio's `Output` window. Press `F5` to debug your application, then select `Debug->Windows->Output` from the main menu, you will see your text there.