# How to see QTest results

Tags: qt, visual-studio-2013, qtestlib, qt5.3

I am using QTest of Qt 5.3.2 to execute some unit tests on a class. I am using VS2013 Express to build the tester. The VS project file is generated from a .pro file using qmake. For running the tests I added the QTEST_MAIN to my source file.

The project builds and the tester executeable work fine. However I have problems seeing the results (e.g. PASS output). While the test is running a console window opens receiving all the testing output. If the test is finished the console window closes immediately and I can't actually see what it displayed. Especially I can not see if some tests failed.

I suppose QTest uses stdout as default output channel. So I tried the VS debugger option "Redirect stdout to output window" but it had no effect.

So how is this supposed to work?

Should the testing output actually go to a newly opened console window? Then why isn't it kept open? Or should the entire testing output go to the VS debugger output panel? Is there a way to redirect the output?

Comment: Why do not you simply run your test (application) from the console (command line)? Leave VisualStudio alone.

Comment: Because it is much easier to debug the tested code and to improve the tests when using the VS IDE. I mean that is what an IDE is made for. There must be a simple solution I suppose.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you have the `Visual Studio Add-in` installed for your version of `Visual Studio`? If not you should download it from [qt-project.org/downloads](http://qt-project.org/downloads).

I did a simple [qt test](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qttestlib-tutorial1-example.html) and imported the `*.pro` file inside `Visual Studio` and ran the test; for me everything works fine and the window stays open showing the resume of the tests:

[image]

What I recommend is writing the [example](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qttestlib-tutorial1-example.html), importing it in Visual Studio using the `Visual Studio Add-in` and compare the project settings. Chances are a flag needs to be changed somewhere in order for the window to stay opened.

It also could be that you need `Console (/SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE)` linker option set. Right click on the project, go to the project `Properties`, choose `Configuration Properties>Linker>System`. For the `Subsystem` property in the right-hand pane, click the drop-down box in the right hand column. Now choose `Console (/SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE)` and reran the test(<kbd>Ctrl+F5</kbd> *and NOT just* <kbd>F5</kbd>)(1).

If you run the test in `Debug` mode (i.e. pressing <kbd>F5</kbd>) your window won't stay open. If you want it to stay open you need to add a `getch()` call in your test destructor, and when your test finishes the window will stay up waiting for input(e.g. `Enter`):

For my test code would be:

```
#include <QtTest/QtTest>
#include <conio.h>

class TestQString: public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
private slots:
    void toUpper();

public:
    ~TestQString()
    {
        getch();
    }
};

void TestQString::toUpper()
{
    QString str = "Hello";
    QCOMPARE(str.toUpper(), QString("HELLO"));
}

QTEST_MAIN(TestQString)
#include "testqstring.moc"
```

(1) - [How to keep the console window open in Visual C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/454681/how-to-keep-the-console-window-open-in-visual-c)

Comment: No, I can't see the results there. But what do you mean with "export"?

Comment: @Silicomancer By export I meant what you said about redirecting(I tried the VS debugger option "Redirect stdout to output window"). But please see my edits.

Comment: Currently I am using the Express version of VS 2013. This means I can not install plugins :-(

Comment: I check the console option. It is already configured as you proposed. Anway when running with Strg+F5 the window stays open. That's pretty weird. Seems I need to code my own main function including a waiting call :-(

Comment: `when running with Strg+F5 the window stays open` - isn't this what you want? Why do you need to write your own function, then?

Comment: Not exactly what I had in mind. I would like to use the debugger the same way. On the other hand when using the debugger I can easily set a breakpoint instead. So you are probably right that this is a sufficient solution.

Comment: It works perfectly now. I used the following code in the destructor:        if (IsDebuggerPresent())
       {
          cout << "Press a key to continue...";
          getchar();
       }