# DirectX11 Application and Console simultaneous

Tags: c++, winapi

I just try to write a little game with DirectX.
Therefore I need a console for writing Debug Informations.
I googled and found the function `AllocConsole()`.
The function works fine, but after the console openes it closes itself and the DirectX Application. 
Does somebody know how I can run a DirectX Application and a Console simultaneous?

Comment: When compiling there is a flag that suppresses the console, if you remove that, you should be able to see the console to... never mind.

Comment: Another option to dump debug information is [OutputDebugString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363362.aspx). The output shows up in Visual Studio's *Output* pane, when the application is run under the debugger. When not running under a debugger, the output can be logged using tools like [DebugView](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896647.aspx).

Comment: What I do is create the console in a separate thread. Then I redirect the cin and cout functions to the console. You can probably try that.

Answer (score 0):

Allocating your own console is unnecessary, most of the times its only needed when you want multiple console, heres how you enable the inbuilt one : https://stackoverflow.com/a/1152873/351861

Comment: A process cannot be attached to multiple consoles. See [AllocConsole](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681944.aspx): *"A process can be associated with only one console, so the **AllocConsole** function fails if the calling process already has a console."*

Comment: *"its only needed when you want multiple console"*

Comment: exactly. One call in each new process - or else manual console-creation and pipe-control would be required.