# C printf() not returning values

Tags: c, visual-studio-2012, printf

I have a very simple C example program that does a crude count of characters words and spaces from input. The program compiles without error but when tested the program doesn't return any of the int variables via the print function. I am using VS2012 for coding and compiling. Stepping into the code shows that the values are being calculated correctly. Is there something wrong with my code or the compiler?

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define IN 1
#define OUT 0
/* count digits, white space, others */
main()
{
    int c, nl, nw, nc, state;

    state = OUT;
    nl = nw = nc = 0;
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF){
        ++nc;

        if(c == '\n'){
            ++nl;
        }

        if (c == ' ' || c == '\n' || c == '\t'){
            state = OUT;
        } else if (state == OUT){
            state = IN;
            ++nw;
        }

    }

    printf("%d %d %d\n", nl, nw, nc);
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you have output generated to a valid log or window and are looking in the correct place for the output?  Also, on *rare* occasions, output is not flushed, and you should flush explicitly when in doubt.  Are you running this code from the command line? If so it should print. Otherwise if a GUI or something there is probably another mechanism for displaying results.

Comment: Did you break the loop with `EOF`?

Comment: Ah, good point - can he see ANY printf() output in other words.  Something I would have determined right at the outset if I were coding it.

Comment: @rlwheeler Run your program pressing Ctrl + F5. Also you have to press Enter before pressing Ctrl + z

Comment: Works fine for me.  Run it, type some stuff, press ctrl-z, see output.

Comment: "Stepping into the code shows that the values are being calculated correctly" Minor: disagree about line count.  IMO, if input was only "123" or "123\n", both would be 1 line.  I would count lines if the _previous_ character was `'\n'` and initialize the previous variable with `'\n'.

Comment: Note: In C, the 6 standard (C locale) "white-spaces" are `" \f\n\r\t\v"`.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Your loop is permanent. Meaning it doesn't end.. so it doesn't reach the call of `printf`.

EOF is indicator that clearly doesn't work like that here. You must break the loop on a specific key. Like enter for instance, which character decimal representation is 13 for carriage return. 10 for NL.

Comment: Why is his loop infinite?

Comment: It ends if you produce `EOF`.

Comment: That isn't specified automatically.

Comment: @DeltaProxy What is not specified automatically? Can he press simply Ctrl+Z?

Comment: He didn't want to end the loop like that.Or didn't know how to print EOF.

Comment: @DeltaProxy Just why do you think EOF won't work? That's the normal way to detect end of input from stdin (like from any stream).

Answer (score 0):

It works if you run it with `stdin` coming from a file `a.exe < test.txt`. It works if you run it with `stdin` coming from the console on Linux. It does not work if you run it with `stdin` coming from the console on Windows.

It must be some sort of Windows console oddity.

Comment: Works perfectly well in a Windows console, ending with `Ctrl-z`, although the break has to be immediately after a newline.

Comment: then it must have been some cygwin oddity

Comment: If using *bash*, then the usual Unix `ctrl-d` should work even under Windows.

Answer (score 0):

In order to see the actual output, start the debugger with Ctrl-F5. This will keep the console window open.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1152873/3805) for more information.