# How to save images during debugging the code in opencv?

Tags: opencv, visual-studio-2013

Im working on reducing noise from noisy image in OPENCV using different filters. i want to know that how i capture or save the result images during debugging code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can:

1. Save with `imwrite` all your debugging images, better in a specific folder.
2. Use [Image Watch](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/e682d542-7ef3-402c-b857-bbfba714f78d) which will enable you to see all your Mat in a nice and powerful viewer during debugging. Just download and install it. You can access the Image Watch viewer in VS: View -> Other Windows -> Image Watch

I recommend the second approach, which personally I find very useful.
Have a look also at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31241435/5008845) answer.

Comment: do you know if there are such programs/extension for IDEs besides VS?

Comment: @tschale I'm not aware of that, sorry.

Comment: @tschale have a look at [Interactive Visual Debugging of Computer Vision applications](http://docs.opencv.org/master/d7/dcf/tutorial_cvv_introduction.html#gsc.tab=0)

Comment: thank you, this seems really useful at first glance. I'm gonna try it out at the next opportunity

Answer (score 0):

If you can use CLion instead Visual Studio you can utilize the OpenCV Image Viewer plugin, which displays matrices while debugging with just one click. There is also an option to save the image on a disk.

https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/14371-opencv-image-viewer
[image]

Disclaimer: I'm the author of this plugin