# New to Visual Studio - Can't see output

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I have to do a programming project for an optimisation class, that has to be written in C or C++. So I'm trying to figure out Visual Studio 2015. I created a blank project, and opened a new C++ file, where I have the following:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    cout >> "Hello World!/n";
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

When I run it, I get a large blank white popup, and nothing else happens, even if I hit various key on the keyboard or wait for several minutes. It looks like this:

[image: Screenshot 1]

If I close the large popup, nothing happens. What Visual Studio refers to as output from build looks like this:

```
1>------ Deploy started: Project: LinearProgramming, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>Updating the layout...
1>Deployment complete (157ms). Full package name: "53acc796-5708-4314-9034-f2a1f840a4f4_1.0.0.0_x86__eazt3av84y7ym"
========== Deploy: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

Could anyone please explain to me what's going on? How can I create a simple C++ project in Visual Studio 2015 and run it?

Comment: This code shouldn't compile.

Comment: By the way, your microsoft account name is visible in your screenshot.

Comment: In addition to melak47's answer, you might want to check the direction of the `<<` in `cout >> "Hello World!/n";`.

Comment: I don't think anyone here understands the question. The code runs, but you can't see the simple "Hello World". It only gives the exit code for a successful completion.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you selected the "Blank App(Universal Windows)" project template, which is like a Microsoft store application. What you probably want is the "Win32 Console Application" template, which creates an application without its own window (and uses the console for I/O).

Answer (score 2):

This is how I create a Win32 Console Application.

1. Go to `File->New->Project...`
2. Select `Visual C++->Win32->Win32 Console Application` and name the project.
3. In the Win32 Application Wizard press the `Next >` button and be sure `Console application` and `Empty project` are selected, and then hit the finish button.
4. In the `Solution Explorer` right click on `Source Files` and select `Add->New Item...`
5. Select the `C++ File (.cpp)`, name it, and hit the `Add` button.
6. After you change the `>>` to `<<` add the code above and it should run.

Answer (score 2):

The quick answer is to hit ctrl-f5 to open the console. After running your script and showing your output it waits for you to hit a key before closing the console.

I eventually found the answer to the question which can be seen at [How to keep the console window open in Visual C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/454681/how-to-keep-the-console-window-open-in-visual-c/1152873#1152873)