# my code isnt executing visual studio 2017, c++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017

This is what im supposed to do:
Add the following operation to the `class stackType`:

```
void reverseStack(stackType &otherStack);
```

This operation copies the elements of a stack in reverse order onto
another stack.

Consider the following statements.

```
stackType stack1;
stackType stack2;
```

The statement

```
stack1.reverseStack(stack2);
```

copies the elements of `stack1` onto `stack2` in reverse order. That is, the
top element of `stack1` is the bottom element of `stack2`, and so on.The
old contents of `stack2` is destroyed and `stack1` is unchanged.

And here is the code i have for it.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

template<class Type>
class stackType
{
    Type s[10];
    int top, n;

public:
    stackType()
    {
        top = -1;
        n = 50;
    }

    stackType(int size)
    {
        top = -1;
        n = size;
    }

    void push(Type elt)
    {
        if (top < n - 1)
            s[++top] = elt;
        else
            cout << "\n\tstack is full.Can't insert " << elt << endl;
    }

    void pop()
    {
        if (top < 0)
            cout << "\n\tstack is empty.\n";
        else
            cout << "\n\tPoped elt : " << s[top--];
    }

    void display() {
        for (int i = 0; i <= top; i++) {
            cout << s[i] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

    void reverseStack(stackType<Type> &otherStack) {
        //Destroy content of other stack by making top to -1
        otherStack.top = -1;
        //Iterate the current stack and push the elements to other stack
        for (int i = top; i >= 0; i--) {
            otherStack.push(s[i]);
        }
    }
};

int main()
{
    stackType<int> stack1;

    stack1.push(10);
    stack1.push(20);
    stack1.push(30);

    cout << "Stack1 content: \n";
    stack1.display();

    stackType<int> stack2;
    stack1.reverseStack(stack2);

    cout << "Stack2 content: \n";
    stack2.display();
    return 0;
}
```

The code the book gave me was this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>

using namespace std;

template <class Type>
class stackADT
{
public:
    virtual void initializeStack() = 0;
    virtual bool isEmptyStack() const = 0;
    virtual bool isFullStack() const = 0;
    virtual void push(const Type& newItem) = 0;
    virtual Type top() const = 0;
    virtual void pop() = 0;
};

template <class Type>
class stackType : public stackADT<Type>
{
private:
    int maxStackSize;
    int stackTop;
    Type *list;

public:
    void initializeStack()
    {
        stackTop = 0;
        cout << "stackTop " << stackTop << endl;
    }

    void print()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < stackTop; i++)
        {
            cout << list[i] << endl;
        }
    }

    bool isEmptyStack() const
    {
        return(stackTop == 0);
    }

    bool isFullStack() const
    {
        return(stackTop == maxStackSize);
    }

    void push(const Type& newItem)
    {
        if (!isFullStack())
        {
            list[stackTop] = newItem;
            stackTop++;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "Cannot add to a full stack." << endl;
        }
        cout << "stacktop: " << stackTop << endl;
        system("pause");
    }

    Type top() const
    {
        assert(stackTop != 0); //if stack is empty, terminate the program.                            
        return list[stackTop - 1];
    }

    void pop()
    {
        if (!isEmptyStack())
            stackTop--;
        else
            cout << "Cannot remove from an empty stack." << endl;
        cout << "pop: " << stackTop << endl;
    }

    stackType(int stackSize = 100)
    {
        if (stackSize <= 0)
        {
            cout << "Size of the array to hold the stack must be positive." <<
                endl;
            cout << "Creating an array of size 100." << endl;
            maxStackSize = 100;
        }
        else
        {
            maxStackSize = stackSize;
            cout << "maxStackSize " << maxStackSize << endl;
        }
        stackTop = 0;
        list = new Type[maxStackSize];
    }

    stackType(const stackType<Type>& otherStack)
    {
        list = NULL;
        copyStack(otherStack);
    }

    ~stackType()
    {
        delete[] list;
    }

    const stackType<Type>& operator=(const stackType<Type>& otherStack)
    {
        if (this != &otherStack)
        {
            copyStack(otherStack);
        }
        return *this;
    }

    bool operator==(const stackType<Type>& otherStack) const
    {
        if (this == &otherStack)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            if (stackTop != otherStack.stackTop)
            {
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < stackTop; i++)
                {
                    if (list[i] != otherStack.list[i])
                    {
                        return false;
                    }
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    void copyStack(const stackType<Type>& otherStack)
    {
        delete[] list;
        maxStackSize = otherStack.maxStackSize;
        stackTop = otherStack.stackTop;
        list = new Type[maxStackSize];
        //copy otherStack into this stack. 
        for (int j = 0; j < stackTop; j++)
        {
            list[j] = otherStack.list[j];
        }
    }
};

int main()
{
    stackType<int> stack1(50);
    stackType<int> stack2(50);

    stack1.initializeStack();
    stack1.push(23);
    stack1.push(45);
    stack1.push(38);
    stack1.print();

    stack2 = stack1;

    if (stack1 == stack2)
        cout << "stack1 and stack2 are identical" << endl;
    else
        cout << "stack1 and stack2 are not identical" << endl;

    stack2.pop();
    stack2.push(38);

    cout << "**** After pop and push operations on stack2 ****" << endl;
    if (stack1 == stack2)
        cout << "stack1 and stack2 are identical" << endl;
    else
        cout << "stack1 and stack2 are not identical" << endl;

    stack2.push(11);

    cout << "**** After another push operation on stack2 ****" << endl;
    if (stack1 == stack2)
        cout << "stack1 and stack2 are identical" << endl;
    else
        cout << "stack1 and stack2 are not identical" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "my code isnt executing visual studio 2017, c++" The code compiles and runs. So what is your question?

Comment: My window isnt opening up and it is giving me the The thread 0x5914 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x242c has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x8760 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x825c has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The program '[38476] Project3.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).

Comment: Run your code with menu [Debug] => [Start without debugging].

Comment: it just closes the pop up window as soon as it opens

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to keep the console window open in Visual C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/454681/how-to-keep-the-console-window-open-in-visual-c)

Comment: Menu [Tools] => [Options]. In the tree to the left go to [Debugging] => [General], in the list to the right untick "Automatically close the console when debugging stops".

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7XGJR.png)

You need to create a breakpoint at the end of your code (End of your main function).